# Customizing endnotes

Tags: endnotes

I'd like to have a particular costomization in endnotes with `endnotes` package. By default, the note number is joined to the first letter of note text. I'd like to have a fixed space
between the two ones. At this time the result is

> ```
>     1Dfh dfhdfh wertwert ertert 
> asdf asdf dfgh erty rtuy rtuytu
> asdf asdf dfgh erty rtuy rtuytu
>     13Dfh dfhdfh wertwert ertert
> asdf asdf dfgh erty rtuy rtuytu
> asdf asdf dfgh erty rtuy rtuytu
> ```

But, I want it to have like

> ```
>     1  Dfh dfhdfh wertwert ertert
> asdf asdf dfgh erty rtuy rtuytu
> asdf asdf dfgh erty rtuy rtuytu
>     13  Dfh dfhdfh wertwert ertert
> asdf asdf dfgh erty rtuy rtuytu
> asdf asdf dfgh erty rtuy rtuytu
> ```

What setting do I have to modify?

======================================================
ADDENDUM

Sure, even it's trivial...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\begin{document}

\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\footnote{\lipsum[2]}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Help us to help you! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the definition of `\makeenmark` just before the `\theendnotes` command

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

\footnote{\lipsum*[1]}

\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

% modify how \makeenmark works
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility would be

```
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\theenmark\enspace}
```

[image]

If you want to have the code in the preamble, which is probably a good thing to do, just do the following incantation:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theendnotes}{%
  \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}%
}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theendnotes}{%
  \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}%
}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

\footnote{\lipsum*[1]}

\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also adds spacing in the text when you put the footnote...

Comment: @karlkoeller Not if you put the redefinition just before `\theendnotes` (yes, I changed the code after posting it the first time).

Answer (score 4):

Add this lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@endnotetext}
  {\@theenmark}
  {\@theenmark\enspace}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

and you'll have

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@endnotetext}
  {\@theenmark}
  {\@theenmark\enspace}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Some\footnote{\lipsum[1]}text

\footnote{\lipsum[2]}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer is similar to [egreg's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219883/) but egreg is quicker...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\begin{document}

  \footnote{\lipsum[1]}

  \footnote{\lipsum[2]}

  \def\makeenmark{\hbox{\theenmark}\quad}
  \theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: endnotes]

Or for flush left numbering, use

```
\def\makeenmark{\makebox[\parindent]{\theenmark\hfill}}
```

[image: flush left markers]

Comment: “Son come il fulmine, sono il factotum della città” `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Google says "Mab fel mellten, yw factotum y ddinas"... But we all know what happened to Achilles... ;).

Comment: This is Figaro in “Il barbiere di Siviglia”!